# @property vs just declaring getter and setter

Tags: objective-c

Is there any difference in behaviour - either at compile time or at run time - between this code...

```c
// MyClass.h
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) SomeType myProperty;

@end

// MyClass.m
@implementation MyClass

@end
```

... and this code?

```c
// MyClass.h
@interface MyClass : NSObject

-(SomeType)myProperty;
-(void)setMyProperty:(SomeType)myProperty;

@end

// MyClass.m
@implementation MyClass {
    SomeType _myProperty;
}

-(SomeType)myProperty {
    return _myProperty;
}

-(void)setMyProperty:(SomeType)myProperty {
    _myProperty = myProperty;
}

@end
```

Obviously, the former version is more succinct and readable, but is there any difference in behavior? Do the synthesized getter and setter do anything more sophisticated than my straightforward implementation here? Is the declaration of a property distinguishable by introspection functions from declaration of a getter and setter? Are there any other differences I haven't thought of?

Comment: It should be noted that at one time the generated setter code for a retained object was more sophisticated than a simple assignment.  But not sure what it is now like, effectively, since ARC, et al.

Comment: Properties are made to write less code and to simplify the programmer work, that's all the difference.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri That's their primary purpose, but I'm asking about the details of their implementation. Based upon iMartin's answer, your claim that "that's all the difference" is outright factually wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Short answer:* **No difference.** However, some property attributes (`copy` or `atomic`) may require different accessor methods.

*Long answer:* There is a group of introspection functions that allow you to access all `@properties` declared for given class or protocol:

```
class_getProperty
class_copyPropertyList
protocol_getProperty
protocol_copyPropertyList
property_getName
property_getAttributes
```

I don't think any of these functions is useful in production code, because this is basically an implementation detail of the class. Also, there may be a getter/setter exposed in the public interface and a private property hidden in class extension.

Oh, and there's one other difference: Xcode highlights properties and plain getters differently :)

Comment: Under ARC, just special handle for `copy` by calling `-copy`. Also `atomic` would have different accessors, but if you know how to implement them, there is no difference.

Comment: You say these introspection functions wouldn't be useful in production code, but I can think of one scenario where they might be - could they be used with `@dynamic` properties whose implementations generated at runtime, like the Core Data properties? As in, in `resolveInstanceMethod`, you check if the selector name is a getter or setter for an `@dynamic` property using the introspection functions, and if so, use some default property implementation for the class (and if not, throw an exception)? It was in fact mostly that use case that prompted me to ask the question.

Comment: @MarkAmery Yes. Or similarly, there's a model library called Mantle that automatically generates NSCoding, -copyWithZone:, isEqual:, etc. methods for subclasses of its MTModel class based on the subclass' declared properties.

Answer (score 1):

One difference is memory management. You can configure your properties to for example copy the object being set or to use a weak variable. Your code seem to be assuming ARC is active, since you are not releasing the old object and retaining the new object.

Before ARC a typical setter would to something like

```
-(void)setMyProperty:(SomeType *)myProperty {
    if (myProperty == _myProperty) return;
    [_myProperty release];
    _myProperty = myProperty;
    [_myProperty retain];
}
```

Comment: You are right, but the point is, that if you provide correct implementation, there is no difference.

Comment: Sure, if you write the same code as the code being generated for you then there is no difference :D

Comment: Not exactly :) See my answer about introspection. Even if you match the code, so there si _no difference_, there _is a difference_!

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I've only ever written code using ARC, but I believe that non-ARC properties use the `assign` modifier by default, not the `retain` one? Thus the two code samples I've written would have memory management behaviours equivalent to each other under either an ARC or non-ARC environment (although it'd retain the property value under ARC and not under non-ARC), right?

Comment: @MarkAmery "A property of retainable object pointer type which is synthesized without a source of ownership has the ownership of its associated instance variable, if it already exists; otherwise, [beginning Apple 3.1, LLVM 3.1] its ownership is implicitly strong." ... "Using strong by default is safe and consistent with the generic ARC rule about inferring ownership. It is, unfortunately, inconsistent with the non-ARC rule which states that such properties are implicitly assign." from http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#property-declarations

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Your link backs up what I said in my last comment: under ARC, the property (with default property attributes) retains and so does my one-line setter. In non-arc, the property doesn't retain, and neither does my one-line setter. In neither the ARC case  nor the non-ARC case is there a memory management difference between the property and the getter/setter.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you use **ARC**, then there is only a small difference. But none that matters.

Your ivar is @protected.
A @property creates an ivar which is @private.

Generally speaking:
So when you subclass, it is possible for your subclass to directly access the ivar you created, but not the one the property created.

BUT since you put your ivar in the @implementation block, the ivar is never seen by the subclass.

---

**Without ARC** however and SomeType being not an Objective-C object, there is a big difference. Then your setter/getter wouldn't have retain/release messages included.